# JOIN two query results (having WHERE and IN clauses + sub queries)

Tags: mysql, join

Trying to recreate the problem below (not including IN clause and sub-queries):

```
/* this is query 1 */    
Select A.column_1,B.keyValue from table1 as A, table2 as B where
A.someColumn = B.someColumn and B.someotherColumn = 10

/* query 1 gives */
column1 | keyValue
_________________

data-A1 | key-1 
data-A2 | key-2
data-A3 | key-3

/* this is query 2 */
Select AVG(ratings) as ratings, C.keyValue from table3 as C, 
table4 as D where C.someColumn = D.someColumn and D.someotherColumn = 'abc'

/* query 2 gives */
ratings | keyValue
_________________

rating-1 | key-1 
rating-2 | key-2
rating-3 | key-3

/* this is the desired result */

column1 | ratings | keyValue
_________________

data-A1 | rating-1 | key-1 
data-A2 | rating-2 | key-2
data-A3 | rating-3 | key-3
```

I googled it up, found mysql join is the solution

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.column1, table1.column2 FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

But this a very basic example involving only two tables, my first query actually involves 5 tables and second query involves 4 tables with multiple WHERE and IN clauses + sub queries. I am unable to implement this JOIN logic with my complex queries having. This is what I tried but its giving me an error after "JOIN" keyword :

```
Select * from (Select A.column_1,B.keyValue from table1 as A, table2 as B 
where A.someColumn = B.someColumn and B.someotherColumn = 10) as first
JOIN
Select * from (Select AVG(ratings) as ratings, C.keyValue from table3 as C, 
table4 as D where C.someColumn = D.someColumn and D.someotherColumn = 'abc')
as second ON first.keyValue = second.keyValue;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would probably help your question more to show sample input data as well.

Comment: I have mentioned the query result data in my question.

Comment: I didn't ask to see the result, I asked for sample table data.

Comment: An aggregate function without a group by clause is unlikely to product the result you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your 4 tables but based on your 2 queries, you can do the following:

```
select
   X.column_1,
   Y.ratings,
   X.key_value 
From
   (
      Select
         A.column_1,
         B.keyValue 
      from
         table1 as A,
         table2 as B 
      where
         A.someColumn = B.someColumn 
         and B.someotherColumn = 10 
   )
   X 
   INNER JOIN
      (
         Select
            AVG(ratings) as ratings,
            C.keyValue 
         from
            table3 as C,
            table4 as D 
         where
            C.someColumn = D.someColumn 
            and D.someotherColumn = 'abc' 
      )
      Y 
      on X.keyvalue = Y.keyvalue;
```

X and Y are called derived tables.

P.S: It might be possible to create a better query if we know the structure of your underlying tables, sample data and what you are trying to achieve. This is the best answer I can give you based on the information.